# Flutter Cupertinopage route, get current route?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to get the current route / class / widget out of cupertinopageroute in Flutter?

I am trying to achieve this for the notifications in the chat app, if route is chat -> ignore, otherwise show the notification.

I have tried the recommended ways and few plugins but they do not seem to work with cupertinopageroutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```